# How to fix version problem when installing TTR

Tags: r, installation, package

I'm new in R programming. Want a run little script for TTR package, but getting version error

Here is my code part

```
options(repos=(CRAN="https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=TTR"))
install.packages("https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=TTR")
```

and here is error I get

```
Warning: unable to access index for repository https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=TTR/src/contrib:
cannot open URL 'https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=TTR/src/contrib/PACKAGES'

Warning message: package 'https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=TTR' is not available (for R version 3.4.4) 

Error in library(TTR) : there is no package called 'TTR'
```

but when I run TTR library from https://rdrr.io/snippets/ , it works well, and R version in the link is 3.4.4

How can I solve this problem?

EDIT: I see this question [How should I deal with "package 'xxx' is not available (for R version x.y.z)" warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721884/how-should-i-deal-with-package-xxx-is-not-available-for-r-version-x-y-z-wa), but can not find my solution

Comment: use `install.packages("TTR")`

Comment: again errors, but belows answer was helpful, and solved my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried it with your command, and i get the same error. But using the standard way with `install.packages` does the job.

You can install the package with:

```
install.packages('TTR', dependencies=TRUE, repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')
```